# SSIS Package failing in SIT environment

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that uses ZappySys HTML table source to connect to the web. When I run the package pointing to an environment, it runs successfully, but when I execute the package in SSISDB, it throws error "     OnError View Contex df_WeatherData:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on HTML Table Source returned error code 0x80131500.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

```
OnError View Context        df_WeatherData:Error: System.Exception: Table not found for specified criteria
```

at ZappySys.PowerPack.Adapter.HtmlTableSource.HtmlTableHelper. (String  , WebClient  , TableFetchSettings  , Boolean  , Boolean  , List`1&  ) at ZappySys.PowerPack.Adapter.HtmlTableSource.HtmlTableHelper.GetTableData(String url, WebClient webClient, TableFetchSettings settings, Boolean fetchColInfo, Boolean fetchData, List`1& colInfoList, List`1& linksTable, List`1& imageTable, Int32& rowsAdded)
at ZappySys.PowerPack.Adapter.HtmlTableSource.HtmlDataExtractor.Process(HtmlDataExtractArgs args)
at ZappySys.PowerPack.Adapter.HtmlTableSource.HtmlTableSource.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPrimeOutput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, IDTSBuffer100[] buffers, IntPtr ppBufferWirePacket)"

Please help, I have been trying to debug this issue days now. Thanks

Comment: _Table not found for specified criteria_ are you certain both environments are pointing at the same HTML source?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the Environment variables values from my package, does not match with the affected environment values, which is causing the job to fail after deployment.